# Custom Mute/Unmute button with javascript for all audio files

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I have many sounds with html5 audio tag in my webpage.

I wanna create mute/unmute button for all my sounds. What i did is the below

Here is the markup

```
<span class="soundIcon soundIconOff"></span>
<audio id="startTop_sound" src="sounds/startTop.mp3" preload="none"></audio> // one of the audios

if(!jQuery('.soundIcon').hasClass('soundIconOn')){
        jQuery('body').addClass('audioOn');
        jQuery('body audio').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).prop('muted', false);
        });
}else{
   jQuery('.soundIcon').removeClass('soundIconOn').addClass('soundIconOff');
   jQuery('body audio').each(function(){
       jQuery(this).prop('muted', true);
   });
}
```

This is not working properly when am clicking on the button during one sound is playing. It did not turn the sound on.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: See my question updated @vvtx